# Laravel auth:api - use token in header instead of request body

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

It's my first time creating an API, I'm using laravel 5.5.

I created a simple `GET` endpoint with `auth:api` as the only middleware.

When I access the endpoint using the API token in the request body (i.e. `http://localhost/my-endpoint?api_token=123`), it works, but I don't want it like that.

How can I make laravel to accept the token also in header? (i.e. `Authorization: Bearer 123`)

**EDIT:**

Here is my route code:

```
Route::get( '/my-endpoint', function(){
    dd( 'hello world' );
})->middleware( 'auth:api' );
```

Comment: what is the error you have  face while passing in header

Comment: Today I learned that using standardized approach to data transfer via HTTP is ugly and not professional.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: @N.B. ,as far as I know, REST API shouldn't contain query strings, and all of the big companies use header for authorization.. But lemme know if I'm wrong

Comment: @Amarnasan I want to use `Authorization: Bearer` header instead of passing the `api_token` as parameter

Comment: @NanThiyagan I just get redirected to the login page.

Comment: @StyleSh1t there's no reason why a REST api shouldn't or can't contain  a query string. However, you **DO NOT** need a reason to use `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header.  If you think that it benefits you or you just want to make it work that way, that's all the reason you need. The `it's ugly` or `it's not professional` is just a silly excuse, it's just ridiculous to say something like that.. anyway, did you try to use that header with Laravel before asking this question?

Comment: Query string is perfect way for filtering data.

Comment: @N.B. OK, thanks for explaining that. And yes, I tried and it doesn't work. It redirects me to the login page as I said.

Comment: post your middleware code

Comment: @NanThiyagan it's the default middleware code...

Answer (score 2):

You must alter table to add 'api_token' field.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('api_token', 60)->unique(); // Add api_token field
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now, you can use **Bearer token** with **Authorization** in header.

https://medium.com/@sirajul.anik/laravel-api-authenticate-user-with-custom-driver-different-table-using-auth-middleware-fa2cabec2d61

Comment: @StyleSh1t Can you give us your mistake if there is?

Comment: As written in my question, my API is working, but only when passing `api_token` field in the request, while I want to pass it in the header

Comment: What route did you create and in which file? Can you give us more code by editing the first topic? Here, an example: https://github.com/ssi-anik/laravel-custom-auth/blob/master/routes/api.php

Comment: Edit which file to add the code that alters users table?

Answer (score 0):

For details on this api authentication, [follow this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074976/how-to-resolve-laravel-401-unauthorized-error/68957842#68957842)

If indeed you are able to pass it into the parameters successfully, then include it in the header object like you would any other header...

```
axios({method: 'get', url: 'api/user', headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yourToken,
    }})
    .then((response)=>{ 
      console.log(response.data)
    })
```

I say this because there's usually additional steps for the api to work, but if it works in your get parameter, then thats all you need

OR better still, pass it by default for all request

```
//js/main.js

axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': your_csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yourToken,
    
};
```