# How to resolve Laravel 401 (Unauthorized) error

Tags: laravel, axios, unauthorized

How to resolve Laravel 401 (Unauthorized) error for a particular single URL.

url is accessible directly but when request send using axios its how this error.

Comment: Show  the code of the controller and the middleware. Also is this an api?

Comment: how is your authentication working ? coockie session ? jwt ?

Answer (score 1):

api_token: this.user.api_token

```
         axios.post("http://foo",
         {headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ api_token}})
         .then(response => {
                    //action
                })
```

link: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/401-unauthorized-vuejs-laravel-and-passport/59770

or

```
       postComment() {
      axios.post('/api/posts/'+this.post.id+'/comment', {
        api_token: this.user.api_token,
        body: this.commentBox
      })
```

but make sure that you have "user.api_token"

Answer (score 0):

Some people just assume all has been configured right out of the box; but you need to:

Follow this Laravel documentation to gain api_token for all your users.
[Laravel api authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)

**NOTE:** When you register users, if users api_token in database is still being saved as `NULL`, go to the users model and add `api_token` to fillable array

```
//Model/User.php
protected $fillable = [
        ...
        'api_token',
        ...
    ];
```

In your view layout `app.blade.php` create a meta for your token, just like your `csrf`:

```
//views/layout/app.blade.php   

<!-- APIToken -->
<meta name="api_token" content="{{ Auth::user()->api_token }}">
```

Finally in your `main.js` or `app.js`; you can include it with every sent request

```
//resources/app.js

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ document.querySelector('meta[name="api_token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  };
```

This works and would help someone after all I've been through; meanwhile Laravel Passport and Sanctum are better recommendation for api authentication